# INNER JOIN in jq

Tags: json, jq

Using the input given, I need to join the true "user" value from the tweets array with the id in the users array and display the users array object as part of the tweets array

**Input:**

```
{
  "tweets": [
    {
      "tweet": "Hey, i gonna release GPT4 soon",
      "user": 1
    },
    {
      "tweet": "We have launched falcon 10 yesterday, it was awesome, one step closer to Mars",
      "user": 2
    },
    {
      "tweet": "Databar acquires Statista.com, great news coming out",
      "user": 3
    },
    {
      "tweet": "Gpt4 is available",
      "user": 1
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "a" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "b" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "c" }
  ]
}
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "tweet": "Hey, i gonna release GPT4 soon",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "tweet": "We have launched falcon 10 yesterday, it was awesome, one step closer to Mars",
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "b"
    }
  },
  {
    "tweet": "Databar acquires Statista.com, great news coming out",
    "user": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "c"
    }
  },
  {
    "tweet": "Gpt4 is available",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "a"
    }
  }
]
```

I tried using an if condition to find the equal values first, but it loops through the entire array, hence I cant get the specific value of the value in the users array that the ID is equal too

Comment: What have your tried ? can you post your if condition please ?

Comment: if (.users[].id == .tweets[].user)  then .users[].name else null end

Comment: I was trying to find the equivalent ID's first but then I don't know how to get the entire object in the users array with the equivalent value

Answer (score 3):

Build an `INDEX`, then use that to map your tweets:

```
INDEX(.users[]; .id) as $idx | .tweets | map({ tweet, user: $idx[.user|tostring] })
```

or using `JOIN` directly:

```
[JOIN(INDEX(.users[]; .id); .tweets[]; .user|tostring; .[0] + { user: .[1] })]
```

You could also do it the inefficient way, finding the correct user by iterating:

```
.users as $users
| .tweets
| map({ tweet, user: (.user as $user | $users[] | select(.id == $user))})
```

Answer (score 0):

@knittl's solutions using INDEX are fine unless there is a "collision" of ids (e.g. if .id can be both `1` and `"1"`).

To avoid collisions and to allow other types of `.id` values, you could use
`SAFE_INDEX` and `lookup` defined as follows:

```
def SAFE_INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    ($row|idx_expr) as $ix
    | .[$ix|type][$ix|tostring] = $row);

def lookup($value):
   .[$value|type] as $t
   | if ($t|type) == "object" then $t[$value|tostring] else null end;
```

So a generic solution to the problem would look like this:

```
SAFE_INDEX(.users[]; .id) as $idx 
| .tweets
| map({ tweet, user: (.user as $user | $idx |lookup($user)) })
```